# C#のAsync/Awaitの処理で発生するエラーの特定方法

Tags: c#, pdf, stream

C#で実装中の処理で以下のエラーが発生するのですが、発生理由の特定ができておらず、デバッグしようにも再現ができていません。
考えられるエラー内容またはエラーの発生条件について少しでも分かることがあればアドバイスいただけませんでしょうか。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

##### エラー内容

```
 9372 2022-XX-XX XX:XX:XX ERROR XXXX.Web.HttpModule - Application error.
Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
Source: System.Web
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.<ProcessRequestAsync>d__554.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.TaskAsyncHelper.EndTask(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: XXXX.XXXXProject.PDFGenerater
   at XXXX.XXXXProject.PDFGenerater.Api.Generater.<Generate>d__34.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at ASP.XXXXProject_PdfDownload_ascx.<AsyncInPage>d__1.MoveNext() in c:\XXXXProject\XXXX\Website\XXXXProject\PdfDownload.ascx:line 99
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.UI.PageAsyncTaskManager.<ExecuteTasksAsync>d__3.MoveNext() 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.<ProcessRequestAsync>d__554.MoveNext()
```

##### 発生箇所のコード

```
            using (var memoryStream = await generator.Generate(viewModel, language))
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("inline; filename={0}.pdf", partno));
            Response.OutputStream.Write(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
            Response.Flush();
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
```

##### Generateメソッドの中身

```
            public async Task<MemoryStream> Generate(PdfViewModel viewModel, Language language)
        {
            var pdfDocument = new C1PdfDocument()
            { 
                ImageQuality = ImageQualityEnum.High,
                FontType = FontTypeEnum.Embedded
            };
            pdfDocument.Clear();

            var pdfFont = new PdfFont(viewModel.RegionCode);

            //ヘッダー、フッターの呼び出し
            CreateContent(pdfDocument, viewModel, pdfFont);

            //ページ番号の取得
            int pageCounter = 1;
            for (int page = 0; page < pdfDocument.Pages.Count; page++)
            {
                var currentPageText = viewModel.Footer.FooterPageText
                ?.Replace("{0}", pageCounter.ToString())
                ?.Replace("{1}", pdfDocument.Pages.Count.ToString());

                pdfDocument.CurrentPage = page;

                pdfDocument.DrawString(
                   currentPageText.ToString(),
                   pdfFont.Font12px,
                   footerBrush,
                   new Rectangle(new Point(530, 680), new Size(120, 20))
               );
                pageCounter++;
            }

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            pdfDocument.Save(ms);
            pdfDocument.Dispose();
            return ms;
        }
```

Comment: 再現しないとなると、ここでは解決できない可能性があります（解決したかどうかわからないため）。見た限り、 `currentPageText` が null になることを想定している一方で`.ToString()` を直接呼び出しているのが気になります。

Comment: 何を何で作っているか書けませんか？ (例: ASP.NET MVC アプリを Visual Studio 2022 を使ってフレームワーク .NET Framework 4.8 で作ってます)

Comment: タイトルに「async/await・・・」とありますが、元々同期で async await を使う意味がなさそうですけど？ それがあるから問題と言うわけではないかもしれませんが・・・

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。使い慣れておらず失礼がありましたら申し訳ありません。

@v..snow 様
解決できない可能性については残念ながら承知しております。その上でご指摘のような気になる点を示していただけるのはとても助かります。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @WebSurfer  様
基本的なことが出来ておらず申し訳ありませんでした。以後、気をつけます。
ASP.NET MVC アプリをVisualStudio2017を使って.NetFramework4.7.2で作成しております。PDFの生成にはComponentOneという製品を利用しております。

Comment: エラーの読み方からなっておらず、Generateメソッドの中の何処かでエラーとなっているのか、generator.Generateのgeneratorがnullになっているのか、async/awaitのときに各インスタンスがどういう状態になるのかという基本的な点から確認しているところです。

Comment: asp.net というタグがありますのでそれを付けていただいた方が良さそうです。

Comment: async/await の使い方をきちんとした方がいいと思います。それ以前に ASP.NET では今回のような CPU バウンドの処理を非同期で行っても意味がありませんので、async/await を使うという余計なことはしないように見直すことをお勧めします。今回の問題とは直接関係ないかもしれませんが・・・

Comment: 勘違いしているかもしれないので念のため書いておきます。async というのはただの修飾子です。メソッドが非同期であると指定するとともに内部で await を使えるようにするものです。async を付与したからと言って非同期になるわけではありません。詳しくは Microsoft のドキュメントを見てください。async (C# リファレンス): https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async